# Splitting the values in column

Tags: python-3.x

I have rows with string like this in below:

`Cherry, Not specified; Vanilla, Not specified`

I want to modify and make a new column where the values are such:

```
Cherry, Not specified <-- Row 1
Vanilla, Not specified <-- Row 2
```

How can i get this Output

Comment: Hi Anurag. When asking a question on Stack Overflow, it's best to include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This demonstrates the effort you have made to solve the problem on your own, and it also gives a small (minimal) bit of code that community members can run and see exactly where you encounter an error or get the wrong output (reproducible). Please provide such an example, and then the community will be happy to help.

Comment: That said, what you're looking for is the [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method of the `str` type. You would use it here as `"Cherry, Not specified; Vanilla, Not specified".split("; ")`.

Comment: You could do `for line in 'Cherry, Not specified; Vanilla, Not specified'.split(';'):` and then indent the next line and type `print(line.strip())`